# Content-type='application/json+merge-patch' in TRestRequest

Tags: rest, http, delphi

Environment: Delphi 10.4.1, Windows 10

I create an application using REST components to communicate with server-side using published API.
One of the method requires content-type=application/json+merge-patch.
As I see, Delphi has not the type in REST.Types.pas.

Could you offer me any workaround?

I tryed to define content-type with Header-parameter, but then I have error with code 500 from the server.

```
FRequestSettings.ClearBody;
FRequestSettings.Method := rmPatch;
FRequestSettings.AddBody(settings.ToJSON);
FRequestSettings.Params.AddHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json+merge-patch');
FRequestExecutor.ExecuteRequest(FRequestSettings, 'TUserSettingsManager.PatchSettings', False, False, 1);
```

Comment: I tweaked REST.Client.pas to set FClient.ContentType only when its empty. That allows to force the ContentType to a custom value. 
The whole concept of having an enumeration for the content type is a big fail from the beginning.
https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-31997

Comment: The solution for Delphi alter than 10.2 is there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56430564/trestrequest-is-it-possible-to-use-custom-media-types-in-a-post-request

Comment: I cannot see how this would be fixed in 10.2 - even in 10.3 and 10.4 you cannot provide a ContentType outside those defined in the enumeration.

Comment: Exactly. But in the thread the possible solution is provided. And it works :)